# Assign NULL value to Boolean variable

Tags: c#, variables

I am trying to assign `null` value to Boolean variable but it is not taking it

```
bool b = null;
```

Comment: Of course you can use the nullable bool (bool?) however if you just need a "tripple bool" try to finde an other solution like using an enumeration.

Comment: Old joke, still funny: `enum mybool { False, True, FileNotFound };`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For this you need to use following code to assign NULL value.

```
Nullable<bool> b=null;
```

Answer (score 79):

You need to use a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) bool:

```
bool? b = null;
```

Answer (score 26):

C# has two different categories of types: [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) and [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx). Amongst other, more important distinctions, value types, such as bool or int, cannot contain null values.

You can, however, use [nullable version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of value types. `bool?` is a C# alias for the .NET `Nullable<bool>` type (in the same way `string` is an alias for `String`) and can contain null values.