# Unable to pass NULL value to database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, bit, nullable

I have a VB application.
I have a property like

```
Public Structure Deal

 Public IsUser As Boolean?

 End Structure
```

Some other place, I am assigning NULL to it

```
 bject.IsUser = Nothing
```

Now I am passing this as a parameter to SP.

```
 AddParameter(SQLCommand, "@IsUser", SqlDbType.Bit, ParameterDirection.Input, obj.IsUser)
```

Above line throwing error-

[InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.]

Comment: I think you need to parse in `DBNull` instead of `nothing`. There's a difference between the two.

Comment: Check this post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362437/assign-null-value-to-boolean-variable

Answer (score 0):

`Nothing` and `DBNull` are not the same. Following should do the trick:

```
AddParameter(SQLCommand, "@IsUser", SqlDbType.Bit, ParameterDirection.Input, If(obj.IsUser Is Nothing, DBNull.Value, obj.IsUser))
```

Comment: Now it is showing error                                                                "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid."

Comment: Which .NET version are you using?

Comment: I don´t understand the error message. Why does it try to convert something to String? Your SqlDbType is Bit and obj.IsUser is boolean or DBNull. You have to include all of your code. There must be something else.

Comment: Probleam is I am unable to pass DBNull value to database.     Below line of code not working                                                AddParameter(SQLCommand, "@IsUser", SqlDbType.Bit, ParameterDirection.Input, DBNull.Value)

Comment: Which database and version are you uisng?

Comment: on which object do you call `AddParameter` ? Please try the following `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsUser", DBNull.Value)` where `com` is your `SqlCommand` object.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass your variable as db null instead of nothing

```
bject.IsUser = DBNull.Value
```